# How to changes CPUShares for cgroup `docker`

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04, cgroups

I have Ubuntu 20.04, docker-ce 20.10.9, cgroup v1

When I start docker container, apperently docker, creates a cgroup `docker` with `cpu.shares=1024`.

Where I can set the custom value of `cpu.shares` for this whole cgroup?

I can set custom `cpu.shares` for specific container - `docker run --rm --cpu-shares 2048 -ti ubuntu:20.04 bash` and this container will get `cpu.shares=2048`, but the parent cgroup will still have `cpu.shares=1024`

What I to achieve: have kubernetes cluster, each node have, f.e. 16 core, for `kubepods` cgroups assigns `cpu.shares=16384`, when all pods start consume CPU, container running in `docker` cgroup, such as `kubelet`, can use only about 5%, in case if other containers in `docker` cgroup is idel, of all time of CPU. I want to make different and set `cpu.shares=2048` for `doker` cgroup - to allow kubelet work faster in moment of heavy CPU load